# Cakephp 3.6.14: redirect after action deny

Tags: php, cakephp, authorization, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to `deny` some actions for non-admin users in my controllers. So in the controllers I am using this code:

```
public $components = array('Auth');

public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    if($this->Auth->user('role_id')==1 or $this->Auth->user('role_id')==2){ //role: 1 admin, 2 project manager
        $this->set('is_admin', true);
    }
    else
    {            
        $this->Auth->deny(['index','delete']);
        $this->set('is_admin', false);            
    }        

    $this->set('my_id', $this->Auth->user('id'));
}
```

So now anytime a user that is not admin or project manager tries to perform `index` or `delete` actions, is redirected to the "Method Not Allowed" error page. But I would like to return to the previous page with a message: "You are not authorized to perform this action".

I tried to set `'unauthorizedRedirect' => $this->referer()` in the AppController:

```
  $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'email',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'loginAction' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ],
            'unauthorizedRedirect' => $this->referer()
        ]);
```

But didn't work. The only way I managed to achieve that is by using this code in the `beforeFilter` function of the controller:

```
 if(!($this->Auth->user('role_id')==1 && !$this->Auth->user('role_id')==2 && ($this->request->action === 'index' || $this->request->action === 'delete')){
        $this->Flash->error(__('You are not authorized to perform this action'));
        return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'index']);
    }
```

But it doesn't seem the proper way to do this in all the controllers that I want to deny some actions. Is there another way?

Comment: You might want to look into a more clean solution like [tinyauth](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tinyauth) then, also less code and probably more safe.

Answer (score 0):

Cakephp provides `isAuthorized` function for the same. You can take advantage of it.
Just define isAuthorized in your App controller or in separate controllers(if you want to put separate conditions for each controllers.)

```
 public function isAuthorized($user)
    {
        $roleArray = [1, 2]; // your role ids array
        if ( !in_array($user['role_id'], $roleArray) && in_array($this->request->getParam('action'), ['index', 'delete'])) {  // put your conditions here
           return false;
        }
      return true;
    }
```

[Cakephp -> Authentication and Authorization -> Authorization (who’s allowed to access what)](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authorization-who-s-allowed-to-access-what)